# How do I access Port Number?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-typescript

I have created `.env` file in my **Reactjs** project root directory.

**my .env file contain:**

```
PORT = 30001 
...
```

**I'm accessing port in App.tsx file like as:**

```
const PORT_NUMBER = process.env.PORT;
```

I got change the port number while run `yarn start` as expected.
**But I got *"undefined"* value of PORT_NUMBER**

one fixes I know is using dotenv package but for now I don't want to use that one. How can I access port number for now?

Comment: Why do you want to know the port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What most React developers don't realize is that the use of `dotenv` in React is a hack.  `dotenv` is a configuration package for **NodeJS** applications *only*.  It doesn't work for browser libraries like React.  The Meta guys, though, made some scripting magic with **Create React App** so it somewhat can be used as a configuration mechanism.  The whole thing is explained in [their website](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/).

Now, I don't really know why you want the port number in React, so I'll just say this much:  If you want a configuration package for your React application, have a look at **[wj-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wj-config)**.  It is a zero-dependency configuration library that works perfectly on both **NodeJS** and **React**, and probably most (if not all) other browser and server-side frameworks and libraries.

Finally, to complete answering you, I would do the following to get the port of the current page:

```js
const currentUrl = new URL(window.location.href);
const port = currentUrl.port
```

You can read about the [port property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/port) at MDN.

Answer (score 0):

You need build your own `.env` parser if you don't want to use `dotenv`.

The reason that `process.env.PORT` result in an undefined is because that Node.js does not read environment variables from `.env`, Node.js only get the environment variables in your system. That's why you need `dotenv` or build your own `.env` parser...